# Selecting specific features based on correlation values

Tags: python

I am using the Housing train.csv data from Kaggle to run a prediction.
https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data?select=train.csv

I am trying to generate a correlation and only keep the features that correlate with SalePrice from 0.5 to 0.9.  I tried to use this function to fileter some of it, but I am removing the correlation values that are above .9 only.
How would I update this function to only keep those specific features that I need to generate a correlation heat map?

```
data = train
corr = data.corr()
columns = np.full((corr.shape[0],), True, dtype=bool)
for i in range(corr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i+1, corr.shape[0]):
        if corr.iloc[i,j] >= 0.9:
            if columns[j]:
                columns[j] = False
selected_columns = data.columns[columns]
data = data[selected_columns]
```

Comment: so you want  a dataframe with only those column, and all others columns dropped?

Comment: yes, if that is possible, please.

Comment: I have done the same in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
col = data.columns

c  = [i for i in col if data[i].dtypes=='int64' or data[i].dtypes=='float64']   # dropping columns as dtype == object
main_col = ['SalePrice']        # column with which we have to compare correlation

corr_saleprice = data.corr().filter(main_col).drop(main_col)    

c1 =(corr_saleprice['SalePrice']>=0.5) & (corr_saleprice['SalePrice']<=0.9)
c2 =(corr_saleprice['SalePrice']>=-0.9) & (corr_saleprice['SalePrice']<=-0.5)

req_index= list(corr_saleprice[c1 | c2].index)   # selecting column with given criteria

#req_index.append('SalePrice')      #if you want SalePrice column in your final dataframe too , uncomment this line

data = data[req_index]  

data
```

Also using for loops  is not so efficient, a direct implementation is favorable. I hope this is what you want!

For generating heatmap , you can use following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

a  =data.corr()
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(a, dtype=np.bool))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
_ = sns.heatmap(a,cmap=sns.diverging_palette(250, 20, n=250),square=True,mask=mask,annot=True,center=0.5)
```

Comment: I tried to plot the correlation with a heatmap and it did not look too good.  Wouold you like to try to generate a heatmap of the results and let me know if it work for you?

Comment: correlations = train[req_index]  

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(correlations)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = 1

sns.set_style('white')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,18))

# Plot heatmap of correlations
sns.heatmap(correlations *100,
            cmap='RdBu_r',
            annot=True,
            fmt='.0f',
            mask=mask,
            cbar=False)
plt.show()

Comment: can you share the image you got, and what you wanted differently in the image?

Comment: That is exactly what I would like.  At what point did you run the code, Is it exactly after loading the data, before doing anything else to it?

Comment: Can you take the absolute value into account?  I noticed that there are no negative numbers on the map, even when the map colors are blue in some areas.

Comment: Blue is not negative, this range from 0 to 1, as you can see there is not a singlre negative correlation. Dark blue will be zero , dark red will be 1, white is 0.5. You can change and edit the intensity colors by changing the **center** parameter in last line of code .It varies from 0 to 1

Comment: Also , you can see the color range with adjacent colorbar plotted with your heatmap

Comment: I understand...  I would prefer to have the negative as well as the positive correlations, but only the high ones.  Such that, all values (negative or positive) that correlates highly with SalePrice.  Specifically at +- >=0.05.  Is that possible?

Comment: yeah sure , you need -0.9 to -0.5 and 0.5 to 0.9 !

Comment: yes, exactly...  I think that would be even better.  don't you?

Comment: I have updated the first part of he answer to include that condition, but it will not affect the output as you can see in your correlation dataframe named **a** , there is not a single negative correlation(just by chance), if there were any , it would show in graph! Hope this helps

Comment: How about using the abs() function.  Would that help to grab all of them?

Comment: you could try abs, but as I have **already  included both condition in my code, there is no negative correlation among any variable**. So there will be no output change, this is the final output and this will remain unaffected how you alter your code.

Comment: take a look at this map:  https://webzest.com/hmap2.png   This is the full correlation map.  I then wanted to grab only the highly correlated ones for a smaller version.

Comment: as you can see , in this map the author has not included any constraint(of 0.5 and 0.9 and -0.5 and -0.9) , the correlation varies from -1 to 1 . As you can see the negative values are all between (-49 to 0, i.e -0.49 to 0) .But you are from beginning implied that you need the constraint!

Comment: Yes, I generated the large map and pulled all the variables so I can see how they are behaving.  here is a larger map with a bar to display the negative values in dark blue: https://webzest.com/hmap3.png